# Question about calcuating this residue.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the residue of $$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}$$ at $z=1$ now it is clear that $(z-1)^2$ vanishes at $1$ and so does it's first derivative hence it has a zero of order $2$. This I get but then I don't understand the solution from here it says...

Since $e^z$ does not vanish at $z=1$ we have that $f(z)$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=1$. Why is this true? Is it just because $e^1=e$ so the series representation is exactly the same just multiplied by a constant so the zero of order $2$ just becomes a pole of order $2$ when you take the reciprocal?

Then we just find $\text{Res}(f,1)$ using the limit method which I get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First method: putting $\;f(z)=\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}\;$

$$\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)f(z)\;\;\;\text{doesn't exist, whereas}\;\;\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)^2f(z)=e\implies \;z=1$$

is a double pole and its residue is

$$\lim_{z\to1}\left((z-1)^2f(z)\right)''=\left(e^z\right)''|_{z=1}=e$$

Second method: Develop in power series about $\;z=1\;$ :

$$\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}=\frac e{(z-1)^2}e^{z-1}=\frac e{(z-1)^2}\left(1+(z-1)+\frac{(z-1)^2}2+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac e{(z-1)^2}+\frac e{z-1}+\frac e2+\ldots\implies z=1$$

is a double pole and the function's residue at that point is $\;e\;$